# p:commandLink won't redirect to new page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I'm using JSF2 and GlassFish, PrimeFaces 2.1.

This works, `showCreateProfile()` method gets hit, and the method returns "profileForm" and the browser redirects to that page:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{profileHandler.showCreateProfile}" value="#{msg.menu_createNewProfile}" />
```

However, this doesn't work, `showCreateProfile()` method get hits, and the method returns "profileForm" but the browser does not redirect to the page. I tried three different things with no luck:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{profileHandler.showCreateProfile}" value="#{msg.menu_createNewProfile}" />

<p:commandLink action="#{profileHandler.showCreateProfile}" value="#{msg.menu_createNewProfile}" ajax="false" />

<p:commandLink action="#{profileHandler.showCreateProfile}" value="#{msg.menu_createNewProfile}" ajax="false" immediate="true"/>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Primefaces' `p:commandLink` fires by default an ajax request. It does not return a whole HTTP response, but only a partial HTTP response which has got to be updated in HTML DOM tree by JS.

You have basically two options:

1. Disable ajax by `ajax="false"` attribute. It'll then fire a normal HTTP request.
2. Update (re-render) the partial content (on the same page!) by `update="clientid"` attribute. You can use `rendered` attribute to control the rendering of content.

If neither works, then the problem lies somewhere else. Since the `h:commandLink` works and the action method of `p:commandLink` also get executed, then it can only mean that you're not running the code you think you're running while trying the `ajax="false"`. Verify, save, rebuild, redeploy, restart.

Answer (score 4):

PrimeFaces does not support forward based navigations, You need to use redirect instead of forward if you want to navigate within a ajax request or set ajax to false as BalusC said.