# How to trigger a p:fileDownload without triggering validation

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to trigger a `p:fileDownload` using PrimeFaces from a command button in a data table.

It is working with `Ajax="false"`, but I need to ensure page validation is bypassed. I have tried setting `immediate="true"` on the command button but it doesn't work.

Any advice appreciated.

Should `immediate="true"` work in this instance?

Comment: Reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900531/jsf-primefaces-pcommandlink-wont-redirect-to-new-page

Comment: Please put the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually because my data table was not writing the selected value to the bean, because Immediate was set to true.  So I was trying to download a null....I am now using an Ajax row select listener to write the selected object to the bean, so it is working now....

Thanks

I